# FireFox and IE convert original color values to RGB

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, ckeditor

UPDATE: the problem is with FF's .cloneNode() method: http://jsfiddle.net/beCVL/1/

I know FF and IE internally convert color to RGB, which causes problem, because the color values don't match what is on the server.

Proof:

```
Chrome 18:
CKEDITOR.instances.selected_text_actual.getData()
>> "s <span style="color: #ff0000">text</span>"

FireFox 11:
CKEDITOR.instances.selected_text_actual.getData()
>> "s <span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">text</span>"
```

So, the way I want to solve the problem is to make CKEditor's data processor always use the rgb values. Is there a way to do that?

I found that something like this should work:

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function( ev ){
            var editor = ev.editor,
                dataProcessor = editor.dataProcessor,
                htmlFilter = dataProcessor && dataProcessor.htmlFilter;

            // HTML 4 way to end tags
            dataProcessor.writer.selfClosingEnd = '>';

            htmlFilter.addRules({
                elements:{
                    $:function(element){
                        var e = jQuery(element);
                        e.css("color", e.css("color")); // jquery auto converts to rgb
                    }
                }
            });

        });
```

Source: http://sebduggan.com/blog/customising-ckeditor-settings-in-mura/
but, there is no change.

The conversion to RGB is pretty straight forward:

```
a.attr("style", "color: #444")
[
<div style=​"color:​ #444">​</div>​
]
a.css("color", a.css("color"));
[
<div style=​"color:​ rgb(68, 68, 68)​;​ ">​</div>​
]
```

EDIT: the problem is with FF's .cloneNode() method: http://jsfiddle.net/beCVL/1/

Comment: What do you mean by "the color values don't match what is on the server"? String wise? Because `rgb(255, 0, 0)` is exactly `#ff0000`.

Comment: that isn't exact. one is in hex, the other is RGB. I think I'm being very literal, but.. idk. =\

Comment: Are you referring to the colour each notation produces, or the actual notation itself?

Comment: the literal string representation to match on a .equals / == comparison.

Answer (score 1):

As I replied to you in http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=25141 you can use the original "output HTML" sample that contains the full code that has been copied in the blog that you linked and use the convertRGBToHex function as it does.

And BTW, Firefox respects the styles, the only browser that currently changes that part is IE.

Comment: But then, why does the CKeditor in FF return something different than the CKeditor in Chrome?

Comment: For me they return the same thing. I don't know how you are performing your tests. My test is: go to http://ckeditor.com/demo, clear the contents and type hello. select all and apply a color, switch to source. I get this: <p><span style="color:#ff0000;">Hello</span></p>

Comment: this is how I'm  getting the text:   var yourEditor = CKEDITOR.instances.selected_text_actual;
  var formattedDataForWysiWyg = yourEditor.dataProcessor.toHtml(yourEditor.getData());
  var temp_sel = yourEditor.dataProcessor.toDataFormat(formattedDataForWysiWyg);

Comment: You shouldn't call the editor.dataProcessor by yourself. Those operations are handled by the editor and usually you won't get what you want. Did you try the steps that I described?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare two color values that can each be represented in several different ways, then you have to make sure both are converted to a canonical form (e.g. the exact same form).

So, you can use `rgb(x,y,z)` as your canonical form if you want, but you will have to make sure that any color values expressed as `#xyz` or `#xxyyzz` are first converted to the rgb form before comparing.

Here's a function that converts three values of colors all to `rgb(x,y,z)` with no spaces and then compares them and returns to you the result:

```
function colorsAreSame(c1, c2) {
    var space = /\s+/g;

    function makeRGB(c) {
        var r, g, b;
        c = c.replace(space, "");
        if (c.charAt(0) == "#") {
            if (c.length == 4) {
                r = parseInt(c.charAt(1), 16);
                r = (r * 16) + r;
                g = parseInt(c.charAt(2), 16);
                g = (g * 16) + g;
                b = parseInt(c.charAt(3), 16);
                b = (b * 16) + b;
            } else if (c.length == 7) {
                r = parseInt(c.substr(1, 2), 16);
                g = parseInt(c.substr(3, 2), 16);
                b = parseInt(c.substr(5, 2), 16);
            }
            return "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
        } else {
            return(c);
        }
    }
    c1 = makeRGB(c1);
    c2 = makeRGB(c2);
    return(c1 == c2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that cloning a node changes the style attribute is almost certainly a [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=742030) in Gecko but in the mean time `element.style.color` will return `rgb(255, 0, 0)` in both cases.